# Something is wrong with my push method, i think

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I have a generic list class(main class) that's implementing a stack class, i will show the push part of the main class below: (s1 is a copy of the list generated through a copy constructor)

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) // push 1000 times with i+100
    s1.Push(i+100);
cout << "*Push(i+100) 1000 times\ns1=" << s1 << endl;
cout << "s1.Size()=" << s1.Size() << endl;
cout << "s1.IsEmpty()=" << ((s1.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s1.IsFull()=" << ((s1.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
cout << "s1.Peek()=" << s1.Peek() << endl;
cout << endl;
```

The method i have for pushing is:

```
`void Push(T item)
    {
        Node *p = new Node;
        p -> data = item;
        p->link = top;
        top = p;
        num_items++;
    }`
```

The output i'm expecting to receive is:

```
*Push(i+100) 1000 times
s1=129 128 127 126 125 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 116 115 114 113 112 111 110 109        108 107 106 105 104 103 102 101 100 
s1.Size()=30
s1.IsEmpty()=F
s1.IsFull()=T
s1.Peek()=129
```

but instead i recieve this output which i will post in an image below.

[image]

Edit:
When i change it to only pushing 100 stacks this is the output i get,

[image]

The left in the white is the expected output, i hope that adds clarity.

Comment: So you're saying you would expect a bunch of space after "109" in the output and aren't getting it?

Comment: Your "expected output" block is exactly the same as the actual output you posted as an image

Comment: You need to at least tell us what `s1` is and probably show us it's IO methods. `Push` looks ok (just guessing since you haven't given us that either....)

Comment: @michel-slm i'm so sorry about that, i thought i posted the right image i'm a little tired, i edited it to make it more clear

Comment: @John3136 s1 is a c
opy of the list generated through a copy constructor i have "Stack(const Stack& s)
  {
   *this = s;
  }"

Comment: @lc. no sorry about that i had the wrong image uploaded

Comment: Why do you expect 129 128 etc? The new output looks right to me since you never pop anything off your stack.

Comment: Why would you expect a size of 30 when you are (presumably) `Push`ing 1000 items?

Comment: @lc. the output i'm respecting to receive was given to me in a photo file by my instructor, i'm not really sure why the output would be that, but according to him that's how it should be

Comment: So is the stack maybe supposed to be full after 30 pushes?

Comment: @user1781290 yes 30 is my max size for the list

Comment: Did you enforce this somewhere? Your push does not check it at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This push function works, a big thank you to @user1781290

```
int Push(const T& item)
{
    int res = -1;
    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
    {
        Node *p = new Node;
        p -> data = item;
        p->link = top;
        top = p;
        res = ++num_items;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You may want to let the caller know via some return value that the `Push()` request they just sent wasn't honored, just saying.

Comment: @WhozCraig you mean if num items does = the max size i should return something like -1?

Comment: yes, if you're not going to do the action the caller just requested, you may want to communicate that back to them somehow.

Comment: @WhozCraig i think i've edited it correctly now

Comment: Try that instead. It would be even more robust if `Node` has a constructor that included a `const T&` construction parameter and forward link pointer.